# Ubuntu 1604 Mate, takes 4 Minutes to load, short splash screen and weird Login screen

Tags: 16.04, boot, grub2, login-screen, plymouth

I'm running Ubuntu 1604LTS on a Dell Vostro 1710 and Ubuntu takes forever to load. In addition to this, the plymouth splash screen is always upended, which means I get the kernel messages instead. After this, the Login screen eventually loads but both the screen and the cursor are distorted.

Here are my specs:

```
 System:    Host: jules-Vostro1710 Kernel: 4.15.0-32-generic x86_64 (64 bit gcc: 5.4.0)
           Desktop: MATE 1.12.1 (Gtk 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3) info: mate-panel dm: lightdm
           Distro: Ubuntu 16.04 xenial
Machine:   System: Dell product: Vostro1710 v: Null Chassis: type: 8
           Mobo: Dell model: 0Y183C Bios: Dell v: A12 date: 03/18/2009
CPU:       Dual core Intel Core2 Duo T5670 (-MCP-) cache: 2048 KB
           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 ssse3) bmips: 7182
           clock speeds: min/max: 800/1801 MHz 1: 1797 MHz 2: 1791 MHz
Memory:    No dmidecode memory data: try newer kernel.
Graphics:  Card: Intel Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (primary)
           bus-ID: 00:02.0 chip-ID: 8086:2a02
           Display Server: X.Org 1.19.6 drivers: (unloaded: fbdev,vesa) Resolution: 1440x900@60.00hz
           GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel 965GM GLX Version: 2.1 Mesa 18.0.5 Direct Rendering: Yes
Audio:     Card Intel 82801H (ICH8 Family) HD Audio Controller
           driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1b.0 chip-ID: 8086:284b
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.15.0-32-generic
Network:   Card-1: Broadcom BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY driver: wl bus-ID: 06:00.0 chip-ID: 14e4:4315
           IF: wlp6s0 state: up mac: <filter>
           Card-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
           driver: r8169 v: 2.3LK-NAPI port: 5000 bus-ID: 07:00.0 chip-ID: 10ec:8168
           IF: enp7s0 state: down mac: <filter>
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 160.0GB (48.9% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sda model: SAMSUNG_HM160HI size: 160.0GB serial: S14QJD0Q692270
           Optical: /dev/sr0 model: Optiarc DVD+-RW AD-7640A rev: JD05 dev-links: cdrom,cdrw,dvd,dvdrw
           Features: speed: 24x multisession: yes
           audio: yes dvd: yes rw: cd-r,cd-rw,dvd-r,dvd-ram state: running
Partition: ID-1: / size: 144G used: 71G (52%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda1
           label: N/A uuid: 7a25ded8-420d-4662-bfd8-e4cb0802b480
           ID-2: swap-1 size: 3.21GB used: 0.00GB (0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda5
           label: N/A uuid: 14417f17-fac8-4d22-9684-8201a80823a6
RAID:      System: supported: N/A
           No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
           Unused Devices: none
Sensors:   None detected - is lm-sensors installed and configured?
Info:      Processes: 167 Uptime: 10 min Memory: 1433.2/2992.7MB Init: systemd v: 229 Gcc sys: 5.4.0
           Client: Unknown : mate-session inxi: 2.2.35
'<
```

I hope you can help me. I suspect it has something to do with the graphics and the NVIDIA proprietary drivers. I just wished my system would load in the way I am used to from Ubuntu. I always love that slick login and splash screen and would love to customize those a bit. (choose a different theme at least.
But right now, it takes minutes to boot and the kernel messages aren't nice either

Here is the boot log. Maybe this will help?

```
[[0;1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to start Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data.
See 'systemctl status plymouth-read-write.service' for details.
[[0;1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to start Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data.
See 'systemctl status plymouth-read-write.service' for details.
[[0;1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to start Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data.
See 'systemctl status plymouth-read-write.service' for details.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Braille Device Support.
[[0;1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to start Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data.
See 'systemctl status plymouth-read-write.service' for details.
[[0;1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to start Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data.
See 'systemctl status plymouth-read-write.service' for details.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Braille Device Support.
[[0;1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to start Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data.
See 'systemctl status plymouth-read-write.service' for details.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Braille Device Support.
[[0;1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to start Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data.
See 'systemctl status plymouth-read-write.service' for details.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started LSB: AppArmor initialization.
         Starting Raise network interfaces...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Braille Device Support.
[[0;1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to start Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data.
See 'systemctl status plymouth-read-write.service' for details.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Raise network interfaces.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Braille Device Support.
[[0;1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to start Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data.
See 'systemctl status plymouth-read-write.service' for details.
[[0;1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to start Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data.
See 'systemctl status plymouth-read-write.service' for details.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status /dev/rfkill Watch.
         Starting Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Sound Card.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Found device SAMSUNG_HM160HI 5.
         Activating swap /dev/disk/by-uuid/14417f17-fac8-4d22-9684-8201a80823a6...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Activated swap /dev/disk/by-uuid/14417f17-fac8-4d22-9684-8201a80823a6.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Swap.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target System Initialization.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started CUPS Scheduler.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on CUPS Scheduler.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started ACPI Events Check.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Paths.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on D-Bus System Message Bus Socket.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on ACPID Listen Socket.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Daily apt download activities.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Daily apt upgrade and clean activities.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack Activation Socket.
         Starting Socket activation for snappy daemon.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on UUID daemon activation socket.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Runs Laptop Mode Tools - Polling Service, every 150 seconds.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Timers.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on Socket activation for snappy daemon.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Sockets.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Basic System.
         Starting Accounts Service...
         Starting Thermal Daemon Service...
         Starting Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes...
         Starting System Logging Service...
         Starting Laptop Mode Tools - Battery Polling Service...
         Starting LSB: Speech Dispatcher...
         Starting LSB: daemon to balance interrupts for SMP systems...
         Starting LSB: Set the CPU Frequency Scaling governor to "ondemand"...
         Starting LSB: Record successful boot for GRUB...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Regular background program processing daemon.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started ACPI event daemon.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started D-Bus System Message Bus.
         Starting Restore /etc/resolv.conf if the system crashed before the ppp link was shut down...
         Starting Save/Restore Sound Card State...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started CUPS Scheduler.
         Starting Network Manager...
         Starting Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack...
         Starting LSB: automatic crash report generation...
```

And here is the update

```
> jules@jules-Vostro1710:~$ systemd-analyze blame
>      1min 4.712s plymouth-quit-wait.service
>          30.701s lightdm.service
>          13.991s dev-sda1.device
>           8.762s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
>           7.481s colord.service
>           6.305s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
>           5.332s snapd.service
>           4.014s ModemManager.service
>           3.985s accounts-daemon.service
>           3.847s NetworkManager.service
>           3.212s rtkit-daemon.service
>           2.563s thermald.service
>           2.290s keyboard-setup.service
>           2.270s grub-common.service
>           1.812s resolvconf.service
>           1.578s dev-hugepages.mount
>           1.574s sys-kernel-debug.mount
>           1.573s dev-mqueue.mount
>           1.550s apparmor.service
>           1.302s udisks2.service
>           1.279s systemd-journald.service
>           1.222s console-setup.service
>           1.172s polkitd.service lines 1-23...skipping...
>      1min 4.712s plymouth-quit-wait.service
>          30.701s lightdm.service
>          13.991s dev-sda1.device
>           8.762s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
>           7.481s colord.service
>           6.305s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
>           5.332s snapd.service
>           4.014s ModemManager.service
>           3.985s accounts-daemon.service
>           3.847s NetworkManager.service
>           3.212s rtkit-daemon.service
>           2.563s thermald.service
>           2.290s keyboard-setup.service
>           2.270s grub-common.service
>           1.812s resolvconf.service
>           1.578s dev-hugepages.mount
>           1.574s sys-kernel-debug.mount
>           1.573s dev-mqueue.mount
>           1.550s apparmor.service
>           1.302s udisks2.service
>           1.279s systemd-journald.service
>           1.222s console-setup.service
>           1.172s polkitd.service
>           1.156s irqbalance.service
>           1.044s systemd-modules-load.service
>            949ms systemd-logind.service
>            906ms ondemand.service
>            898ms apport.service
>            821ms systemd-user-sessions.service
>            819ms avahi-daemon.service
>            734ms binfmt-support.service
>            640ms laptop-mode.service
>            634ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
>            623ms ufw.service
>            547ms upower.service
>            532ms sys-kernel-config.mount
>            531ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
>            404ms plymouth-start.service
>            403ms rsyslog.service
>            394ms speech-dispatcher.service
>            375ms systemd-update-utmp.service
>            371ms networking.service
>            353ms kmod-static-nodes.service
>            350ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
>            291ms systemd-sysctl.service
>            283ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
>            163ms systemd-journal-flush.service
>            134ms ntp.service
>            134ms systemd-rfkill.service
>             92ms user@1000.service
>             91ms systemd-random-seed.service
>             70ms systemd-udevd.service
>             66ms wpa_supplicant.service
>             62ms snap-onlyoffice\x2ddesktopeditors-26.mount
>             56ms snap-core-5145.mount
>             56ms snapd.seeded.service
>             52ms gpu-manager.service
>             51ms setvtrgb.service
>             45ms alsa-restore.service
>             45ms snapd.socket
>             43ms dev-disk-by\x2duuid-14417f17\x2dfac8\x2d4d22\x2d9684\x2d8201a80823a6.swap
>             41ms snap-core-4917.mount
>             39ms systemd-remount-fs.service
>             33ms pppd-dns.service
>             23ms hddtemp.service
>             17ms lmt-poll.service
>             16ms plymouth-read-write.service
>             16ms rc-local.service
>             13ms ureadahead-stop.service
>             13ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
>              7ms dev-loop2.device
>              7ms systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service
>              5ms dev-loop1.device
>              3ms dev-loop0.device lines 29-74/74 (END)



drm_kms_helper        172032  1 i915
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
drm                   401408  5 i915,drm_kms_helper
```

Comment: Please add output of `systemd-analyze blame` to the question. HDD is SATA, but 5400 rpm with 8 Mb cache, so it may be slow.

Comment: Got the reply "Bootup is not yet finished. Please try again later."

Comment: I've edited the post to include the output from systemd-analyze blame

Comment: During bootup, I get a message along the lines of "[drm:drm_atomic_helper_commit_cleanup_done [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR*  flip_done timed out."

Comment: Please add output of `lsmod | grep drm` to the question. Also you can try to install better video driver with `sudo apt-get install i965-va-driver`, but it may not help.